# How to add read data to array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a text file with six Product Codes, Product Names and Product Prices, grouped per line. Each line has a diferrent product. I used `for` and `fin` to read data. Now I want to add those data to an array.

The product codes are set as `pcode`, product names as `pname`, product prices as `pprice` and the array as `arrP[]`. I'm told to add those data to an array using `setData`, for which I have a constructor in class `Product`.

Data reading works. However I cannot understand how to use `setData` to add those to `arrP[]`. I've tried `arrP[i].setData(pcode, pname, pprice);` in the same `for` that reads the data but it's obviously wrong because it crashes when it's about to execute that line. Below I quote my code about this part.

This is the code of the function that reads the data and moves it to the array (N is defined as 6):

```
int addptoarray(ifstream &fin, Product arrP[])
{
  Product p;
  int pcode;
  int i;
  char pname[21];
  float pprice;

  n = 0;


  for(i=0; i<N; i=i+1){

  fin >> pcode;

  fin.get(pname, 21);

  fin >> pprice;


  arrP[i].setData(pcode, pname, pprice);


  n = n+1;

  }


}
```

This is the part on main that triggers the function (`N` is defined as 6):

```
[...]
addptoarray(infile, arrP[N]);
[...]
```

This is the code of the constructor for `setData` in `Product` class:

```
void Product::setData(int pcode1, char pname1[], float pprice1)
{
pcode = pcode1;
pname[21] = pname1[21];
pprice = pprice1;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to read some [good book about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/580083). It seems to me that you have not much knowledge about how arrays work in C++. Also, than "plain C" arrays, using some container from C++ standard library (such as `std::vector`) is usually a better option.

Comment: what i usually do if i have to read data with specified text format: 1) make struct which corresponds for text format and operator >> for reading from stream 2) use std::copy to read content of file into back_inserter of vector of struct from (1) . So basically you code shrinks to struct (you need it anyway) and 1 line of actual reading from file. If you need to do something that can be done by algorithm from standard library - it usually best way to do it (leaves no room for errors and easy to read/understand for others)

Comment: `Product::setData` cannot be a constructor: a constructor must have the same name of the class.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't crash because of a seg fault? Are you properly initializing the arrP array? I think we need to check out your entire code to make sure.

Comment: Please add some information about crashing. It might crash also because you are reading more elements than the ones stored. `addptoarray(infile, arrP[N])` is reading the `N+1` element.

Comment: It exits when it tries to execute that line with return value 3221225477

Comment: Also  notes: in your function you are not returning any value. Plus you are defining the function as `int addptoarray(ifstream &fin, Product arrP[])` which is expecting an array but you are calling it `addptoarray(infile, arrP[N]);`: can you try `addptoarray(infile, arrP)`;?

Answer (score 1):

```
char pname[21];
```

Okay, `pname` is an array with 21 entries.

```
void Product::setData(int pcode1, char pname1[], float pprice1)
{
    pcode = pcode1;
    pname[21] = pname1[21];
    pprice = pprice1;
}
```

That middle line doesn't make any sense. The middle line tries to set the value of the 22nd entry in `pname`. Why? Because `pname[0]` is the first entry in `pname` and `pname[1]` is the second entry. So `pname[21] = ...` tries to set the 22nd entry in `pname` to something.

But `pname` only has 21 entries. Trying to set its 22nd entry to something is an access to the array out of bounds.

If you're expecting `pname` to be a string, you have no code that reflects that. It's not actually a string type (C++ has those) and you don't use C-style string function (like `strcpy`) to manipulate it. So it's not going to act like a string at all.